# How to specify taskExecutor in publishSubscribe()

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How to "translate" the following XML configuration to the equivalent Spring integration java-dsl?

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="channel" task-executor="myex">
</int:publish-subscribe-channel>

<task:executor id="myex" pool-size="10"></task:executor>
```

I've read the [DSL Reference Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference), but still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MessageChannels](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference#message-channels) chapter points out to the `MessageChannels` factory. So, `<publish-subscribe-channel>` XML config translates to Java config like:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel channel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(myExecutor()).get();
}
```

Although you can reach the same just with raw Java config:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel channel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel(myExecutor());
}
```